# Why are downvotes automatically removed?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

Yesterday I downvoted a question for being unclear. Today I received a notification "Question Undownvoted".

Does the system undownvote questions/answers automatically? Did someone vote it up and was my downvote removed?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Only you can vote and only you can revert such a vote, so "no", there is no automatic process. Also someone else might "counter" your vote to change the number next to a post, but that doesn't invalidate your vote, it is still there and "alive". Can you maybe add more information, especially what you mean with "a notification question "undownvoted""?

Comment: @Tom in some cases system automatically reverses up/down votes, see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/165773)

Comment: @gnat Yes that's correct. I omitted that in the hope OP wouldn't do that :D.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why down votes are automatically removed?

Only when "the system" has detected suspicious voting behavior.

When, for example, you do targeted voting, the system might observe: "user X is quickly down(up)voting multiple posts of user Y", that might be determined to be serial voting, and the system automatically undos all corresponding votes.

In other words: the system "automatically" undoing your votes is most likely based on specific (unwanted) behavior on your side.

Comment: The question here mentioned a notification of "Question Undownvoted". Is that documented anywhere as happening in a case of serial voting? The answer to the linked duplicate says that there is no notification if the downvote was on a question.